# How to call NSURL for Rate My App properly in xcode?

Tags: ios

Im trying to put in a rate App alert, but its not opening properly, in fact when I click the Yes button it dosnt open the url at all, How do I make it work?

Below is the call in the viewdidload:
The below code in viewdidload is also in app delegate

```
[super viewDidLoad];
//rate app
NSUserDefaults *prefsr = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger launchCount = [prefsr integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
if (launchCount >= 1) {
    UIAlertView *alertRate = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Like this app?" message:@"Rate on the app store." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"No, thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"Remind me later", nil];
    [alertRate show];
}


-(void)alertViewRate:(UIAlertView *)alertViewRate clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndexP{
if (buttonIndexP == 2) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];


}
else if (buttonIndexP == 1){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the delegate Self while creating the UIAlertView

```
 UIAlertView *alertRate = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Like this app?" message:@"Rate on the app store." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No, thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"Remind me later", nil];
[alertRate show];
```

Delegate method for UIAlertView also need to be chnaged

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

if (buttonIndex == 2) {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1){
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the delegate to self while you are creating UIAlertView object. So -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex method is not getting called when you click on buttons in the AlertView.

Change your code From

```
UIAlertView *alertRate = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Like this app?" message:@"Rate on the app store." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"No, thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"Remind me later", nil];
```

To

```
UIAlertView *alertRate = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Like this app?" message:@"Rate on the app store." delegate:self. cancelButtonTitle:@"No, thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"Remind me later", nil];
```